# Dispose SPWeb objects used in feature receiver which creates subwebs

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a feature receiver (scope=web) which creates subwebs below the web, where the feature is activated. This is used for application installation issues.

Is it necessary to dispose the created subwebs if they are returned from my createSubwebs(SPWeb web) method, which is called in the feature receiver?

Comment: createSubwebs(SPWeb web) is my own method to create subwebs. Corrected that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are creating the webs via [`SPWebCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411806.aspx) the short answer is **yes**. `SPWeb` objects returned by `SPWebCollection.Add` always have to be disposed.

For more information see the [Disposing Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee557362.aspx) MSDN article.

**Edit:**
To clarify "returned for further use". Let's assume you have a utility class `WebCreator` with a method `CreateWeb`. This method creates a web and returns this web.

```
public class WebCreator
{ 
  public static SPWeb CreateWeb(SPWeb parent, string name)
  {
    return parent.Webs.Add(name);
  }
}
```

We should not dispose the `SPWeb` object in the method `CreateWeb` since it will be used by the caller. However the caller is responsible to dispose the object.

Comment: what if the web objects **are** returned for further use? Then they also have to be disposed, aren't they? So webs created via **SPWebCollection.Add** always have to be disposed, right?